# Is it a bad idea to capture all click events in a single global event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a project with hundreds of click events attached to various html items.  I would much prefer to have a single handler attached to the body tag, that uses switch/case on the target id to determine what function to run. Compatibility for modern versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox, and IE10+

Simplified example:

```
function clickHandler(e)
  {
  var T=e.target,eT=e.type;
  if(eT=="click")
    {
    switch(T.id)
      {
      case "hH": doStuff();break;
      case "hF": doDifferentStuff();break;
      case ... etc
      }
    }

document.body.onclick=clickHandler;
```

I have begun to implement this and I find it improves readability and maintainability but before I go too far, I want to know if there are some major disadvantages or reasons why this paradigm isn't more commonly used.  For example will a switch/case with hundreds of cases be a huge performance drag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are disadvantages for places where you'd like to stop propagation of events. For example, a typical way of implementing a modal is to stop propagation of clicks on the modal, but then attach an event listener to `document`, whose role is to close the modal. If you only ever place events on `body` (or one element), this will be impossible. I can think of other cases where this inflexibility will become a hindrance, too.

Also, it will be difficult to implement it perfectly, for example, consider this markup...

```
<button type="button" id="click"><span>Click me</span></button>
```

When the user clicks, the target element will be the `span` (most probably). This means when it propagates to `body`, you won't have the `id` attribute to match. You *could* ascend ancestor elements looking for the `id`, but then that's more *work*.

Of course, for this example, you could place the `id` on the `span`, but hopefully the point I'm trying to make is clear.